# Looking for a way to check Software Distribution Agent status

Tags: c#, windows, sccm

So, I'm working on a project where I need to enable/disable the Software Distribution Agent in SMS. However I cant figure out how to get the current status of it. I can do it manually by opening up configuration manager and going to components there it's listed. I need to be able to do this remotely so WMI, Registry or hopefully some other avenue exist. hopefully some of you very smart folks have already done this and I'm just an idiot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for quite a while, but eventually I found the class.

`ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\\" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + @"\root\ccm\Policy\Machine", "SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareDistributionClientConfig"`

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a support for `SCCM` using **WMI**. Link 2 deals more with status API. Link 1 has VBScript which can be easily used as reference for C#.

[Link 1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334615.aspx)

[Link 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949627.aspx)

Comment: I know you sent this last month but I just finally seen it. I looked through those. and have went through every WMI namespace I could trying to find this specific status. I've still been unable to find it.